# MongoDB C# Sort null values last

Tags: c#, mongodb, sorting

I'm using the Mongo C# Driver to filter a table of data. The location (string of a city) field can be empty, and when sorting in ascending order, the results with an empty location come first. I'd like to sort anything with a location first and put those with no location (null) at the end of the list, so when sorting in ascending order, the list will always start with locations A-Z. The filter is quite complex so it uses a filter builder and it gets to the sorting here.

Does anyone know of a way of telling the sort to put the null values at the end of the sort using the C# Mongo library? I'm using the very latest version of the library. I've tried all sorts: projections and coallesing the result to a null (not supported) and nothing seems to work.

I could get two sets of data and glue them together but that feels really messy and perhaps my last resort.

I've Googled for a long time and can't seem to find anyone who's done it.

Any help appreciated.

```
var jobsResults = await collection.FindAsync(filter, new FindOptions<MongoJob>
{
   Limit = criteria?.Take,
   Skip = criteria?.Skip,
   Sort = criteria?.SortByDirection == "asc"
      ? new SortDefinitionBuilder<MongoJob>().Ascending(x => x.Location)
      : new SortDefinitionBuilder<MongoJob>().Descending(x => x.Location),
   Collation = new Collation("en", strength: CollationStrength.Secondary)                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var jobsResults = await collection.FindAsync(filter, new FindOptions<MongoJob>
{
   Limit = criteria?.Take,
   Skip = criteria?.Skip,
   Sort = criteria?.SortByDirection == "asc"
      ? new SortDefinitionBuilder<MongoJob>().Ascending(x => x.Location ?? "zzzzzz")
      : new SortDefinitionBuilder<MongoJob>().Descending(x => x.Location ?? "zzzzzz"),
   Collation = new Collation("en", strength: CollationStrength.Secondary)                
});
```

Comment: Have you tested this?

Comment: Alas Linq doesn't allow the coallesing